# How do I use faster-rcnn frozen_graph_quantized.pb on Android project?

Tags: android, tensorflow

First off, I have never worked with exporting anything for mobile so my knowledge around this is very very minimal, so it might be something stupid.  I am using Tensorflow 1.5 and was provided a faster rcnn frozen_graph_quantized.pb protobuf file and asked to get this to work on Android mobile. I have not been successful in getting this to work on Android as of yet. I am able to run this on the pc without issue though, but I believe my problem may stem from the Android demo project models expecting a certain input.

So I originally was trying some demos I found online elsewhere but none of those seemed to work with the 1.5+ versions of TF. After looking deeper I saw that the API methods had changed or been stripped which were throwing errors.  So I then proceeded to try to get the tensorflow "android" example working and that was a success, however none of these were aligned with faster-rcnn, however I thought it wouldn't be too tough to convert one.

I currently have slightly modified the TFDetect project to point to the path of my protobuf file. It was successfully able to compile and install tot he device, however when I go to run the TFDetect app I receive the below error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.tensorflow.demo, PID: 26085
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find input Node 'image_tensor'
```

In the python logic of the detector we have the below code:

```
def __init__(self, models_path):
        # load config
        cfg_from_file(os.path.join(models_path, "config.json"))
        #load faster graph
        self._graph = load_graph(os.path.join(models_path, "frozen_graph_quantized.pb"))
        # We access the input and output nodes
        self._image = self._graph.get_tensor_by_name('ph_image:0')
        self._im_info = self._graph.get_tensor_by_name('ph_im_info:0')

        # middle points
        rpn_cls_prob = self._graph.get_tensor_by_name('rpn_cls_prob:0')
        rpn_bbox_pred = self._graph.get_tensor_by_name('rpn_bbox_pred:0')
        mode = "TEST"
        anchors, anchor_length = anchor_component(self._im_info)
        self._rois_pred, self.rpn_scores = my_proposal_layer(rpn_cls_prob, rpn_bbox_pred, "proposal_layer", self._im_info, anchors, mode)

        # endpoints
        self._cls_prob = self._graph.get_tensor_by_name('cls_prob:0')
        self._bbox_pred = self._graph.get_tensor_by_name('bbox_pred:0')
```

When running ParseFromString on the graph, I get the following output:

```
['ph_image=>Placeholder', 'ph_im_info=>Placeholder', 'resnet_v1_101_3/rpn_cls_prob_reshape=>Softmax', 'resnet_v1_101_5/cls_prob=>Softmax']
```

I am not sure what I need to do to get this to work with the Android example provided by Google's team. I am still searching on Google to see what may be a solution, but I figured it was worth the time to post here and see if I might get any insight as well.

Thanks!